# Recursive JQuery to format HTML node values in text

Tags: javascript, loops, recursion

```js
function insideNest(theindex, count) {
  count++;
  console.log("(\n)");
  if (theindex == null) {
    theindex = $(document);
  }
  $(theindex).children("#nest").each(function() {
    $(this).children("#value").each(function() {
      $(this).children("input").each(function() {
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
          console.log("\t");
        }
        console.log($(this).val() + "\n");
      });
    });
    insideNest($(this));
  });
  console.log(")\n)");
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  insideNest($(this), -1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nest">
  <div id="value">
    <input type="text" id="hasvalue" value="level1" />
  </div>
  <div id="value">
    <input type="text" id="hasvalue" value="level1" />
  </div>
  <div id="value">
    <input type="text" id="hasvalue" value="level1" />
  </div>
  <div id="nest">
    <div id="value">
      <input type="text" id="hasvalue" value="level2" />
    </div>
    <div id="value">
      <input type="text" id="hasvalue" value="level2" />
    </div>
    <div id="nest">
      <div id="value">
        <input type="text" id="hasvalue" value="level3" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="value">
      <input type="text" id="hasvalue" value="level2" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="value">
    <input type="text" id="hasvalue" value="level1" />
  </div>
  <div id="value">
    <input type="text" id="hasvalue" value="level1" />
  </div>
</div>
```

My Output:

```
(
)
)
)
```

Expected Output:

```
level1
level1
level1
(
  level2
  level2
  (
    level3
  )
  level2
)
level1
level1
```

I want to get the values inside `input` fields, and brackets start only when there is nested `#nest`. I tried to call the same function when javascript finds `#nest` and just print the output when it finds `#value`. I think the trick is to find only one-level children of the `nest`
Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2fq8u8wk/

Comment: You're reusing IDs in the document, so you're not off to a great start. I don't know if jQuery enforces only one result with `.children()` or not. Those should be a class.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact nature of your mistake because I don't want to try to analyze how jQuery will behave.

Instead it's easier just to do a rewrite. This is a simple recursive function that uses the native API to do what you appear to want.

```js
function indent(n) { return "\t".repeat(n) }
function print(depth, s) { console.log(indent(depth) + s) }

function walk(root, depth) {
  print(depth, "(")
  
  for (const ch of root.children) {
    if (ch.matches(".value")) {
      print(depth + 1, ch.firstElementChild.value)

    } else if (ch.matches(".nest")) {
      walk(ch, depth + 1)
    }
  }
  print(depth, ")")
}

// Run after the DOM is loaded
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  walk(document.body.querySelector(".nest"), 0)
})
```

```html
<div class="nest">
  <div class="value">
    <input type="text" class="hasvalue" value="level1" />
  </div>
  <div class="value">
    <input type="text" class="hasvalue" value="level1" />
  </div>
  <div class="value">
    <input type="text" class="hasvalue" value="level1" />
  </div>
  <div class="nest">
    <div class="value">
      <input type="text" class="hasvalue" value="level2" />
    </div>
    <div class="value">
      <input type="text" class="hasvalue" value="level2" />
    </div>
    <div class="nest">
      <div class="value">
        <input type="text" class="hasvalue" value="level3" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="value">
      <input type="text" class="hasvalue" value="level2" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="value">
    <input type="text" class="hasvalue" value="level1" />
  </div>
  <div class="value">
    <input type="text" class="hasvalue" value="level1" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I did change your `id` attributes to `class`, since ID's should be unique in a document. Given my above rewrite, we could get away with IDs, but it's still not great.

Comment: could you use jQuery to do this? elements that are appended in the code later are not being read by the script.

Comment: @code_together_today: That'll also be the case for jQuery. If you're running this before the DOM is ready, then that'll be an issue. I'll add code to ensure it doesn't run until the DOM is loaded. I won't rewrite it in jQuery because that's a bloated and unnecessary dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Similarity based on Crazy Train's response, you can create visit functions. You can control what happens when you visit, during your visit, and after your visit for each node.

```js
const indent = (count, char) => (char || '\t').repeat(count);

function walkDom(node, preVisitFn, visitFn, postVisitFn, depth) {
  preVisitFn(node, depth);
  for (const child of node.children) {
    if (child.classList.contains('value')) {
      visitFn(child, depth + 1);
    } else if (child.classList.contains('nest')) {
      walkDom(child, preVisitFn, visitFn, postVisitFn, depth + 1)
    }
  }
  postVisitFn(node, depth);
}

walkDom(
  // The element we want to walk.
  document.body.querySelector('.nest'),

  // Before we visit children
  function(node, currentDepth) {
    console.log(indent(currentDepth) + '(')
  },

  // While we visit each child (depth +1)
  function(node, currentDepth) {
    console.log(indent(currentDepth) + node.firstElementChild.value)
  },

  // After all children have been visited
  function(node, currentDepth) {
    console.log(indent(currentDepth) + ')')
  },

  // Initial depth is zero.
  0
);
```

```css
.nest { display: none; }

.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nest">
  <div class="value">
    <input type="text" class="hasvalue" value="level1" />
  </div>
  <div class="value">
    <input type="text" class="hasvalue" value="level1" />
  </div>
  <div class="value">
    <input type="text" class="hasvalue" value="level1" />
  </div>
  <div class="nest">
    <div class="value">
      <input type="text" class="hasvalue" value="level2" />
    </div>
    <div class="value">
      <input type="text" class="hasvalue" value="level2" />
    </div>
    <div class="nest">
      <div class="value">
        <input type="text" class="hasvalue" value="level3" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="value">
      <input type="text" class="hasvalue" value="level2" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="value">
    <input type="text" class="hasvalue" value="level1" />
  </div>
  <div class="value">
    <input type="text" class="hasvalue" value="level1" />
  </div>
</div>
```